# convertir texto de ('0','0') a (00)

Tags: python, python-3.x, itertools

El error es sencillo, pero no se como solucionarlo. Al crear una lista a partir del producto del modulo "itertools" e intentar imprimirlo me queda como ('0','0'), cuando lo que yo necesito es (00). ¿Alguna solución?
El codigo es:

```
import string

pwdcomb = string.printable

with open('pwdcomb', 'a') as p:
    comb = list(product(pwdcomb, repeat=2))
    print(comb[0])
```

Como cabe esperar, el print del final escribe `('0','0')`

Answer (score 1):

si tenés una lista y buscas mostrar los elementos seguidos se puede usar el método join() que une los elementos de un iterable a una cadena, entonces es solo declarar una cadena vacía y usar la función y como parámetro el iterable por ejemplo:

```
list = ['0','0']
print("".join(list))
```

lo que devuelve es una cadena

Comment: El resultado esperado por OP es la cadena `(00)`, sin embargo tu código produce `00` sin los parentesis. Igual buena respuesta!

Comment: Podrías usar algo como por ejemplo `"(%s)" % "".join(list)` para tener los parentesis.

Comment: @DanteS. es cierto, es que no tuve en cuenta que quisiera los paréntesis, también se puede: print(f'({"".join(list)})')

Comment: O un simple `print('(' + ''.join(comb) + ')')`